# Call to Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById leaks instance of my Activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services, google-places, leakcanary

When I'm using `Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById()` LeakCanary detects that an instance of my `Activity` has leaked.

Here is what LeakCanary reports

```
* com.mypackage.PlaceSearchActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT com.google.android.gms.location.places.zzl.mContext
* leaks com.mypackage.PlaceSearchActivity instance
```

And this is my code. Both methods are declared within my `PlaceSearchActivity`.

```
void lookupLatLng(final Location location, final int followUpAction) {
    Task.callInBackground(new Callable<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng call() throws Exception {
            PlaceBuffer places = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(
                     getGoogleApiClient(), location.getPlaceId()).await();
            LatLng result = places.get(0).getLatLng();
            places.release();
            return result;
        }
    }).continueWithTask(new Continuation<LatLng, Task<Void>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Void> then(Task<LatLng> task) throws Exception {
            if (task.isFaulted()) {
                // TODO Place lookup failed
            } else if (task.isCompleted()) {
                switch (followUpAction) {
                    case ACTION_PICK:
                        location.setLatLngPoint(LatLngPoint.from(task.getResult()));
                        onLocationSelected(location);
                        break;    
                }
            }
            return task.makeVoid();
        }
    }, Task.UI_THREAD_EXECUTOR);
}

void onLocationSelected(Location location) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, Parcels.wrap(location));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(this);
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: Memory leak is also detected with folowing code.

```
void lookupLatLng(Location location) {
    Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(getGoogleApiClient(), location.getPlaceId()).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                    Place place = places.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    places.release();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

It might be an issue within `PlayServices` library. I'm going to test this on a empty project just to verify the issue.

Comment: It might be a problem with Bolts. Instead of calling the `await()` method to do a synchronous call, have you tried to get the places using `onResult()` callback method? You can see [this detailed implementation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details#get-place) about getting places asynchronously.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. I was using `ResultCallback` as described on the given link before switching to Bolts and memory leak was present. I'll update the question.